# Custom Loss Function with TensorFlow/Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

Im doing a model with a custom loss layer, the model runs 1 epoch and then I get this error that I can't figure out how to solve.

```
    AssertionError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'model_21' (type Functional).
    
    Could not compute output KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 3, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder_2:0', description="created by layer 'out_layer'")
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'model_21' (type Functional):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 72, 72, 28), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

My training and validation data is in the right format.

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

# loss function for angle loss
def angle_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true, axis=-1)  
    y_pred = tf.squeeze(y_pred, axis=-1)

    y_true_normalized = tf.math.l2_normalize(y_true, axis=-1)
    y_pred_normalized = tf.math.l2_normalize(y_pred, axis=-1)

    cosine_similarity = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(y_true_normalized, y_pred_normalized), axis=-1)

    angle_loss = 1 - cosine_similarity
    return angle_loss

# loss function for position loss
def position_loss(n_true, pos_true, y_pred):
    norm_n_true = tf.linalg.norm(n_true, axis=1)
    
    v = pos_true - y_pred
    
    abs_dot_v_n = K.abs(K.sum(tf.multiply(n_true, v), axis=1))
    
    distance = tf.divide(abs_dot_v_n, norm_n_true)
    
    distance_avg = K.mean(distance)
    
    return distance_avg

class CustomLossLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, normal_loss, position_loss, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLossLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.normal_loss_weight = self.add_weight(name='normal_loss_weight', initializer='ones', trainable=True)
        self.position_loss_weight = self.add_weight(name='position_loss_weight', initializer='ones', trainable=True)
        self.normal_loss = normal_loss
        self.position_loss = position_loss

    def call(self, inputs):
        y_true, y_pred = inputs
        normal_loss = self.normal_loss(y_true[0], y_pred[0])
        position_loss = self.position_loss(y_true[0], y_true[1], y_pred[1])
        loss = self.normal_loss_weight * normal_loss + self.position_loss_weight * position_loss
        self.add_loss(loss, inputs=inputs)
        
        self.add_metric(normal_loss, name='angle_loss')
        self.add_metric(position_loss, name='position_loss')
        
        return y_pred
    
def build_model(input_shape):
    input_layer = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name="input_1")
    
    true_labels = [
        tf.keras.Input(shape=(3, 1), name="true_labels_pos"),
        tf.keras.Input(shape=(3, 1), name="true_labels_normal"),
    ]
    
    conv1 = layers.Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_layer)
    maxpool1 = layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = layers.Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(maxpool1)
    maxpool2 = layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv2)
    flatten = layers.Flatten()(maxpool2)
    dense = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(flatten)
    
    # Normal head
    normal_output = layers.Dense(3, name='normal_head')(dense)
    normal_output = layers.Reshape((3, 1), name='normal_output')(normal_output) 
    
    # Position head
    position_output = layers.Dense(3, name='position_head')(dense)
    position_output = layers.Reshape((3, 1), name='position_output')(position_output) 
    
    pred_labels = [normal_output, position_output]
    
    out = CustomLossLayer(normal_loss=angle_loss, position_loss=position_loss, name="out_layer")([true_labels, pred_labels])
    
    model = models.Model([input_layer, true_labels], out)
 
    # Compile the model
    model.compile(loss=None, optimizer='adam', weighted_metrics=[])

    return model


# Build and train the model
model = build_model((72, 72, 28, 1))

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)

# Train the model
history = model.fit([train_scans, train_position, train_normal], 
                    validation_data=([val_scans, val_position, val_normal]),
                    epochs=10, batch_size=1, callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint])
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Adding to my post, this is the ouput before the error :  '''Epoch 1/10
24/24 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.9687 - angle_loss: 0.1540 - position_loss: 0.8221 '''